# Migrate ABP Framework to ABP Commercial

Tags: abp

We are planning to procure ABP commercial license for our new project. In the  mean time we are planning to do R&D/Learning/Development using ABP opensource code. Once we procured our commercial license. Is it easy to migrate our code from open source free version ABP framework to ABP commercial? Do we face any issues?

Comment: 30 days money back gurantee. try the commercial version and if it doesn't work for you, you can get refund your money

Answer (score 1):

ABP Commercial is built on ABP Open-Source Framework, So the answer is both YES and NO.

You don't have to migrate anything, you need to add Commercial features that you need or change the theme as you wish. So, your code once you wrote won't be changed. But you'll able to use commercial modules.

Answer (score 0):

We migrated a simple app from Open Source to Commercial and was easy. We generate all modules again, using **abp suite** and everything compiles OK.